# Read the time,status and accountno from the log file and store those values in a variable

Tags: java

The format of my file is

```
2020-03-06T09:39:14.400+0530::INFO::Login Successful for user : 5 @ sessionId
```

How to parse the file and get only those details?

Answer (score 0):

Use FileReader and wrap it with BufferedReader to read your file.
Then use String.split() method to split those contents separately.
Finally add your splited string to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the line from the logfile, you can see that it's built in a specific way:

```
<Date>T<Time>+<Offset for Timezone>::<Loglevel>::<Logmessage>
```

The Logmessage itself can be broken down even further:

```
<Message> : <accountno> @ sessionId
```

What you can do now is the following:

You can split Strings in Java, and get an array of substrings. For this, you need to give a specific delimiter, that splits the substrings. For example:

For the String `this/is/a/test` with the delimiter `/`, you would get an array that looks like this: `[this, is, a, test]`.

The method that you need to use for this is called `split()`. With the example that I gave above, it would roughly look like this:

```
String test = "this/is/a/test";
String[] substrings = test.split("/");
```

Where `substrings` now contains all the different words.

For your specific example, you could use `::` as a delimiter to split Date, Time and Logmessage, and for the Logmessage you would have to find a similar way of splitting it to get the information you want.